# How to run a .cs file from a winform?

Tags: c#

Looking how to run the `program.cs` file from a winform as I'm trying to run it, hide it and display the text in the textbox but I cannot find a way to run the console separately once the winform has started up!

Comment: Why do you need the console exactly?

Comment: I'm making a remote server thing with a client / serverside console. It works in console mode.

Comment: What means *"run the program.cs file"* ? cs-files contain source, you can't just run source, it has to be compiled, etc. Can you tells us what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You cannot just open any program.cs file and run it. It might reference classes declared in other files or even in other libraries

Comment: I'm trying to run a .cs file and command it through a winform using a text box & buttons etc.

Comment: Its not a .cs file your are running.... .cs isn't an executable

Comment: Are you trying to run the .CS file with Roslyn?

Answer (score 0):

A .cs file is just plaintext as far as I'm aware - You probably need to to actually be executable - From there you can use IPC to communicate between the two processes.

If you have somehow made the program.cs run (Black magic?) you could also get one process to write to a text file, then get the "winform" process to read from it (And then delete it!).

You might try elaborating on your problem, method and environment in your question - There's not a lot to work off here.

Answer (score 0):

Make a console application and add a `WinForm` to do. Show the winform with `.ShowDialog()` and you will have both the console and the winform showing at the same time.

[image: proj]

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dlg = new Form1();

        dlg.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

[image: both]